# robocopy cannot find path

Tags: batch, windows-command-prompt, robocopy, command

i have batch script like bellow:

```
SET SOURCE=F:\Diff\For_VOYAGE\models.pck.files\models\players
SET DESTINATION=F:\Diff\For_VOYAGE\models.pck.files\NEW\models\players
SET LOG=LOG.txt
robocopy %SOURCE%\装备\女\印度舞娘时装上衣 %DESTINATION%\装备\女\印度舞娘时装上衣 /E /LOG+:%LOG%
```

when i execute it, giving me error like bellow:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Sat May 14 20:27:50 2016

   Source : F:\Diff\For_VOYAGE\models.pck.files\models\players\装备\女\印度舞娘时装上衣\
     Dest : F:\Diff\For_VOYAGE\models.pck.files\NEW\models\players\装备\女\印度舞娘时装上衣\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2016/05/14 20:27:50 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Accessing Source Directory F:\Diff\For_VOYAGE\models.pck.files\models\players\装备\女\印度舞娘时装上衣\
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have check path

```
F:\Diff\For_VOYAGE\models.pck.files\models\players\装备\女\印度舞娘时装上衣\
```

I can access it from windows explorer.
but seems the command prompt can't read it.
does anyone have this problem before?
Thank you.

Comment: What result from `dir "F:\Diff\For_VOYAGE\models.pck.files\models\players\装备\女\印度舞娘时装上衣\"`? What happens if you would **copy&paste** mentioned code snippet in an open `cmd` window instead of running batch script?

Comment: Please answer this question by yourself and accept it then. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important. I can't put my answer through my lack of experience with [CJK character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for respond. the problem is already solve. it because i forgot to change batch script encoding type to GBK